# Search Results WebPart: Result preview returns more results than actual

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, query

I am using the search results webpart to return a list of people in a particular department. I set up the query correctly for the webpart and when I do "**Test Query**", it returns 8 relevant results in the "**Search Result Preview**" box.

However, when I apply the query with the "**Show ranked results**" checked under the Settings tab, I only get back 7 people, not 8. Doing a global search also shows up 8 results.

Any ideas on why it is leaving off the 8th person? I have 30 as the setting for "**Number of results per page**"

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by Justas is correct. The issue I was having was that the 8th person was being removed as a duplicate. The option for **"Don't remove duplicates"** has been removed in SharePoint 2013 though. The web part needs to be exported and modified directly.

The solution is described by the following article:
http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2013/04/sharepoint-2013-search-not-display-all-results/

The steps are:

1. Export the web part to your computer. Click on the drop-down for the web part, the 4th option is to export it.
2. Open the file and search for **"TrimDuplicates"**. Change the option from **true** to **false**.
3. Save the file.
4. Go back to SharePoint and edit the page.
5. Click on **Insert** and then **Web Part**.
6. Under the **Categories** section, there will be an option to **"Upload a Web Part"**.
7. Upload the web part from step #3.
8. Go back to step #5 and select the web part you just uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

It might be "Trim Duplicates" functionality interfering, which tries to remove results, which are essentially the same. Not exactly sure how it can happen with People Search, but it's wroth a try. Try disabling this by configuring Search Results web part. Instructions for SharePoint 2013: Edit Page, Edit Search Results web part, click **Change Query**, go to **Settings** tab, Select "**Don't remove duplicates**"

Comment: I went to the Settings tab of the Build Your Query, and I don't have the option for "Don't remove duplicates". The only options I have are:
**Query Rules**,
**URL Rewriting**, and
**Loading Behavior**